# How Can I Use jnative Without Pointer?

Tags: java, native

For example

**C++ code**

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl test(unsigned char *inputBytes,int inputLEN, const unsigned char **outputBytes,int &outputLEN) {............................}
```

**C# NATIVE**

```
 [DllImport("xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            private static extern void test(IntPtr inputBytes, int inputLEN,out IntPtr outputBytes,out int outputLEN);
```

**Java JNative**

```
?
```

Comment: I remember chosing *Java Native Access* over JNative because of things like this. It is possible, but requires a lot of boilerplate code. (at least some time ago) If you are not stuck with JNative, you might consider switching to JNA where this is simple:  https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/ByRefArguments.md